# CakePhp3.2 ORM ResultSet and ORM Query Error running skeleton app on shared host

Tags: cakephp

Been running cake app on shared host, which worked great until recently. The shared host supports Apache,PHP 5.4.45 through to PHP 7.0.21 and Mysql Server 5.6.35.

FYI - A skeleton app throws up the same error. This error is thrown way before database connection is made.

Below is the error am getting, the same app works ok on my local server.

Fatal error: Class Cake\ORM\ResultSet contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Iterator::current) in /projects/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/ResultSet.php on line 593

> Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Cake\ORM\ResultSet in /vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Query.php on line 922

Looking forward to your insights on above.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it looks like that this is the result of a bug in PHP:

- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/10936**
- **https://github.com/cakephp/chronos/issues/147**
- **https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74833**

Make sure to update to the latest CakePHP version, and if you the problem persists, try switching to PHP 5.6 until a fixed PHP version, or a workaround is available.

Comment: thanks for your quick response, i have confirmed that the server php version is 5.6.31.

Comment: @JoelKimilu If that is the case, and the problem still persists with the latest CakePHP version too, then there probably isn't much you can do, other than trying different PHP versions or switching to a different hoster and hoping for a lucky hit.

Comment: Tried changing PHP versions with the host, same same problem. will sleep over it - again, hope  a solution comes up soon. Thanks for your patience though, If you stumble upon a resolve do not hesitate to let me know.